# Countable companions for Polish locally compact groups and their orbit equivalence relations

Tags: gr.group-theory, ergodic-theory, topological-groups, descriptive-set-theory

In "Countable sections for locally compact group actions" (Ergod. Th. & Dynam. Sys., 1992), Kechris proved that if $G$ is a Polish locally compact group acting in a Borel way on a standard Borel space $X$, with orbit equivalence relation $E_G$, then there is a countable Borel equivalence relation $E$ such that $E_G$ is Borel bireducible to $E$. In particular, $E_G$ is *essentially countable*.

In "Countable Borel equivalence relations" (J. Math. Log., 2002), Jackson, Kechris and Louveau, when discussing the above result, asked whether there is a "countable companion" to $G$? In other words, given $G$ as above, is there a countable group $\tilde{G}$ such that every $E_G$ is bireducible to some $E_{\tilde{G}}$ (arising from some action of $\tilde{G}$)?

(Of course, the Feldman-Moore Theorem implies this is true for each particular $E_G$, as any countable Borel equivalence relation $E$ is induced by *some* countable group, but gives very little information about that group, nor is it uniform in $G$.)

There are cases where this is known to be true, but they all seem to be when $E_G$ is essentially hyperfinite, such as when $G=\mathbb{R}$, in which case one can take $\tilde{G}$ to be $\mathbb{Z}$.

My question is: Has any additional progress (positive or negative) been made on the above question regarding countable companions to locally compact groups $G$, beyond hyperfinite cases? For example, I am thinking of when $G$ is a (nonamenable) matrix or Lie group.